# Blueimp/jQuery File Uploader didn't work with pretty URL's? (SyntaxError: Unexpected token...)

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, friendly-url, blueimp

```
RewriteRule ^edit_storage/(.*)$ ./edit_storage.php?object_key=$1
```

That's how I have my pretty URL for page with Blueimp.

If wrote url like that: `/edit_storage/12345678` - nothing work, but if: `/edit_storage?object_key=12345678` - it's fine, no any problem here.

"nothing work" in sense, that gui of Blueimp is loaded, but without already uploaded files. And if try to upload something I have an error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`

Why? How to fix that?

---

My index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/plugin/blueimp/server/php/UploadHandler.php");
session_start();
$options = array (
                'upload_dir' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/load/'.$_SESSION['object_key'].'/',
                'upload_url' => '/load/'.$_SESSION['object_key'].'/',

                'image_versions' => array(
                    'thumbnail' => array(
                        'upload_dir' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/show/'.$_SESSION['object_key'].'/',
                        'upload_url' => '/show/'.$_SESSION['object_key'].'/',

                        'max_width' => 100,
                        'max_height' => 100
                    )
                )
            );
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
?>
```

---

---

Info:

HTML: Apache-PHP-7-x64

PHP: PHP-7.1-x64

---

/ps: My page starting with:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/engine/auto_include.php"); ?>
<?php
set_time_limit(5);

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/engine/get_functions.php");

$thisObjectID = $_GET['object_key'];
$object_key = $_GET['object_key'];
$original_id = $_GET['original_id'];
...
```

---

## For someone that will have the same problem!

Fix is been very simple, but didn't very obviously.

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#uploadTable').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    //url: 'server/php/',
    url: '/plugin/blueimp/server/php/', //Need to add "/" or "../" in start of string. Facepalm. Who is thought to do it work like that?
    ...
});
```